# How does XML Schema declarations work and refer to each other?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

There is something fundemental I don't understand about Xml Schema declarations. I have the following declaration in an .xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="tile">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-z][0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="move">
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="T" type="tile" />
        </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

So, for example `<move><T>a0</T><T>v5</T></move>` should be a valid XML element according to the xsd file. (I've simplified the actual declaration, so the move may not make sense)

Background: I am developing a project in C# 4.0. I use this xsd file as a project source. When I receive an XElement from somewhere, I first check whether it is valid according to the xsd above. The C# code works OK.

Here is my question (hopefully a single question, asked three times):

1) I want to put my declarations on a domain. Let's say `aliferhat.com`. Or do I want to? Why should I want to do that? How can I do that? How can I use that declaration later from somewhere else?

2) I will have many similar xsd files. Most of them will use the "tile" definition, so I want to put the part "tile" on a seperate file, and refer to that file from other xsd files. How can I do that? How will the system know where to look for definitions?

3) This is what the visual studio generates when I add a new XSD file to the project:

```
<xs:schema id="temp"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/temp.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/temp.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/temp.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
</xs:schema>
```

What does `xmlns:xs` and `targetNamespace` attributes do? Are `xs:element` and the rest really defined in one of these URIs? Do the C# compiler really look up those URIs for the definitions?

I hope and guess I have asked only one question. I've read the "XML schema definition" page on W3 schools but could not find the answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx). It might help you get a better understanding.